# Detect if time difference is negative in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to detect if timedifference is negative in below code. My `data` is pandas dataframe.

```
data['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.starttime, format = '%H:%M:%S.%f') #2014-10-28 21:39:52.654394
data['endtime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.endtime, format = '%H:%M:%S.%f')     #2014-10-28 21:37:18.793405
if (data.endtime- data.starttime) < 0:                                     #-1 days +23:57:26.139011
  data['timediff'] = (data.endtime- data.starttime)
```

Above code does not detects time difference is negative or not. It throws me error-

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int
```

Comment: can you add how is your data ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
data.endtime - data.starttime
```

Is giving you a `timedelta` object, you can't compare that directly to an integer, but you should be able to do

```py
duration = data.endtime - data.startime
if duration.total_seconds() < 0:
    data['timediff'] = duration
```

Or compare the two `datetime` objects directly with something like

```py
if data.endtime > data.starttime:
    data['timediff'] = (data.endtime - data.starttime)
```

**Note**   -   The logic here assumes that `data.endtime` and `data.starttime` are single `datetime` objects, in the case where they represent an array or array-like of `datetime` objects (e.g. a `DataFrame` with more than one row) you will need to iterate over them instead.